# Where is the restore function in the DHIS 2 admin panel?

Tags: dhis2

I couldn't find the restore function to import demo database in the admin area of dhis2-live.

Answer (score 1):

The DHIS 2 Live package or the DHIS 2 software itself do not provide a function for restoring a database backup file. This should be handled using import tools available for your database system.

If you use PostgreSQL you can use the [psql](https://www.dhis2.org/doc/snapshot/en/implementer/html/ch08s06.html) tool. You can learn how to crete and restore dumps in the DHIS 2 documentation [here](https://www.dhis2.org/doc/snapshot/en/implementer/html/ch08s06.html).